# How can I outline (LaTeX) text in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, typography, inkscape, text, svg

This is a difficult question to google, as the term "outline" does not mean the same in Inkscape as it does in, e.g., Powerpoint.

However, Powerpoint does not support Latex.

How can I outline a LaTeX word generated with the ["Tex Text"](http://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/) extension so that it is clear when placed over an underlying figure?

Here is a picture of what I would I have tried (and a [link to the inkscape svg file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18092793/overlay_test.svg):

[image]

Comment: additional tag suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You could try `dvisvgm` to get svg files.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this a 'hack', but it does reflect the intent.

The general idea is to copy the original text, convert it to white, and then make many more copies.

The many white copies are then moved next to each other so that they create an inflated version of the word in white.

Then the original black version is placed on top, and the background image placed below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the tool to edit paths `(F2)`. Then, select your text and transform the text into a path `(Shift+Ctrl+C)`. Now, Ungroup the text into several paths `(Ctrl+U)`. As you have standard paths now you can set the stroke of the objects or you can copy the text and use dynamic offset to get an object that can be used as outline. Note that you can now longer alter the text or its text properties after you have converted it into a path. Hope this is what you are after. I don't know whether you can solve this without transforming the text into a path.

Comment: sort of what I am after, except it is not clear how to 'set the stroke'. When I try to increase the width under 'stroke style', nothing happens. Also, how do I do 'dynamic offset'?

Comment: also, it is not clear to me if the letters are 'text' or something else; they are generated with the "Tex Text" extension

Comment: If you can set the "Stroke style" of the text then it is already a path. Did you set the "Stroke paint" as well?

Comment: I am sorry, but I was wrong. I have checked your file and the object appears to be neither a path nor a text. Therefore, you cannot do much with it. I did not have this case before.